# Implicit instantiation of the template within its own definition

Tags: c++, templates, language-lawyer

Let's consider simple example about template implicit instantiation:

```
#include <iostream>
template<int N>
class A
{
    static const int a = A<N-1>::a; //1, OK, doesn't require implicit intantiation
};

template<int N>
class B
{
    static const int a = B<1>::a; //2, Error, implicit instantiation of template 'B<1>' within its own definition
};


int main(){ }
```

**[DEMO](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/b867cfe840a27eb9)**

The standard wasn't clear about that fact. What it says is only that `N3797::14.7.1/1 [temp.inst]`:

> Unless a class template specialization has been explicitly
>   instantiated (14.7.2) or explicitly specialized (14.7.3), the class
>   template specialization is implicitly instantiated when the
>   specialization is referenced in a context that requires a
>   completely-defined object type or when the completeness of the class
>   type affects the semantics of the program.

Neither 1 nor 2 don't require the class type to be completely defined, however the second one causes the error about implicit instantiation. I'd like to understand why.

Comment: @Columbo And...? Look at [this](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/2d2abfc3f4282931) . `A` is incomplete at `//2`.

Comment: Are you looking for exact chapter in standard? Otherwise, it is quite obvious that `B` should not compile (what would you expect `a` to be equal to?). `A` will not compile as well if you try to instantiate it : `int main(){ std::cout << A<3>::a; }`. But it will compile if you define explicit specialization for some `N`, e.g. `template <> class A<0> { static const int a = 42; }`. I see no reason it should work differently.

Comment: @frymode Yes, I am. That's why I cited the quote from the standard.

Comment: @frymode BTW, why can't we implicitly intantiate a template within its own definition. What chapter does it prevent?

Answer (score 1):

I think the reason `B<1>` fails immediately and `A<N-1>` not is because of [temp.res#general-8.4](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4868/temp.res#general-8.4)

> The validity of a template may be checked prior to any instantiation. The program is ill-formed, no diagnostic required, if:

> a hypothetical instantiation of a template immediately following its definition would be ill-formed due to **a construct that does not depend on a template parameter**